# Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, mongodb.driver

I am unable to return the response. Tried each and every solution available but no result.
The request is passed to the controller action and action uses builders function to query mongodb.
I am getting the response but unable to return in "Ok()" method. It's giving me above error.

```
                var builder = Builders<Campaign_Rules_Promo_Create>.Filter;

                var filter = builder.And(builder.Eq("rules.product", "flight"),
                                        builder.Eq("rules.type", flight.type),
                                        builder.Eq("rules.from_iata", flight.from_iata),
                                        builder.Eq("rules.airlines.iata", flight.airline),
                                        builder.Eq("rules.cabin", flight.cabin),
                                        builder.Eq("rules.flight_number", flight.flight_number),
                                        builder.Eq("rules.rbd_include", flight.rbd));

                var projection = Builders<Campaign_Rules_Promo_Create>.Projection.Include("rules").Exclude("_id");
                var result = _campaigns_rules_promo.Find(filter).Project(projection).ToList();


                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception("Error occured",ex);
            }
```

```
 public class Campaign_Check_Request_Flight
    {
        public string promo { get; set; }
        public string product { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string from_iata { get; set; }
        public string to_iata { get; set; }
        public string airline { get; set; }
        public string flight_number { get; set; }
        public string rbd { get; set; }
        public int adult { get; set; }
        public int child { get; set; }
        public int infant { get; set; }
        public float amount { get; set; }
        public string travel_date{ get; set; }
        public string cabin { get; set; }
        public bool registered { get; set; }
        public string device { get; set; }
        public string user_id { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public enum campaign_rules_promo_status { active, inactive }
 
    public class Campaign_Rules_Promo_Create
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string campaignid { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }

        public string status { get; set; }

        public bool codeless { get; set; }

        public List<Schedule> schedule { get; set; }
        public List<object> rules { get; set; }
        public List<string> effects { get; set; }

        public string created_by { get; set; }

        public DateTime created_on { get; set; }

    }
```

**here's mongodb json document**

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f5a04de0128aa38ca8fb4b0"},"campaignid":"5f59ea343f42c6e124d19327","name":"PROMO INDIA 2020","status":"active","codeless":false,"schedule":[],"rules":[{"_t":"Campaign_Flights","product":"flight","type":"multi_city","from_iata":"BOM","from_city":"Mumbai","to_iata":"LHR","to_city":"London","cabin":["economy"],"airlines":[{"iata":"AI","name":"Air India"}],"flight_number":["AI634"],"rbd_exclude":[],"rbd_include":["W"]},{"_t":"Campaign_Flights","product":"flight","type":"multi_city","from_iata":"BOM","from_city":"Mumbai","to_iata":"LHR","to_city":"London","cabin":["economy"],"airlines":[{"iata":"AI","name":"Air India"}],"flight_number":[],"rbd_exclude":[],"rbd_include":["W"]},{"_t":"Campaign_Flights","product":"flight","type":"multi_city","from_iata":"BOM","from_city":"Mumbai","to_iata":"LHR","to_city":"London","cabin":["economy"],"airlines":[{"iata":"AI","name":"Air India"}],"flight_number":[],"rbd_exclude":[],"rbd_include":["W"]},{"_t":"Campaign_Flights","product":"flight","type":"one_way","from_iata":"BOM","from_city":"Mumbai","to_iata":"LHR","to_city":"London","cabin":["economy"],"airlines":[{"iata":"AI","name":"Air India"}],"flight_number":[],"rbd_exclude":[],"rbd_include":["W"]},{"_t":"Campaign_Hotels","name":"hotel booking rule 1","product":"hotel","cityid":"1234","city":"Mumbai","hotels":[{"_id":"878687","name":"Hotel Taj Mansingh"}],"star_category":[0],"blackouts":[{"from":"18:00","to":"19:00"}]}],"effects":[],"created_by":"Sudarshan","created_on":{"$date":"2020-09-11T10:07:57.238Z"}}
```

**here's request json**

```
{
  "promo":null,
  "product": "flight",
  "type": "multi_city",
  "from_iata": "BOM",
  "to_iata": "LHR",
  "airline": "AI",
  "flight_number":"AI634",
  "rbd":"W",
  "adult": 2,
  "child": 0,
  "infant": 1,
  "amount": 98000.00,
  "travel_date": "20-10-2020",
  "cabin":"economy",
  "registered": true,
  "device": "android",
  "user_id": "_a6hdfhkdhfdljelkrlerke"
}
```

**Here's the stack trace exception**

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'.
   at get_AsBoolean(Object )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.OnWrite(WriteStackFrame& current, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.Write(WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post whole exception object including stacktrace?

Comment: Posted the exception. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked query in my computer. I don't have Exception.

How you create `_campaigns_rules_promo`?

Here my example:

```
IMongoCollection<Campaign_Rules_Promo_Create> _campaigns_rules_promo;
var mongoUrl = MongoUrl.Create("mongodb://localhost:27017/local");
var mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(mongoUrl);
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientSettings);
var db = mongoClient.GetDatabase(mongoUrl.DatabaseName);
_campaigns_rules_promo = db.GetCollection<Campaign_Rules_Promo_Create>("test");
```

Comment: The response result shows error. No error on server side.

Comment: So strange. Because, I don't have error. Here full example: https://pastebin.com/S7VYk5TH

Comment: You are using var t = result[0]; How can i pass the complete result?

Comment: result - List<BsonDocument>, t - BsonDocument. result - full response

Comment: If you need, you can deserialize BsonDocument. `var myObj = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(bsonObject);
Console.WriteLine(myObj);`

Comment: I understand about problem. Problem here: `return Ok(result);` You try return `List<BsonDocument>`, but `rules` -  you should deserialize first

Comment: How can i do that? result is an array.

Answer (score 0):

You tried return `List<BsonDocument>`, you can return Campaign_Rules_Promo_Create:

```
var result = _campaigns_rules_promo.Find(filter).ToList();
return Ok(result);
```

When you work with `Projection`, you should deserialize result, use `BsonSerializer.Deserialize`